# How do I get the most recent message in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Every time a message is sent in a specific channel, I want to print it to the console (with console.log). I am also going to color it with `npm install colors`. I go everywhere, even on Stack Overflow, but I cannot seem to find any information. I am coding a Scholastic Bowl-helping bot. Below is the code I have tried (I found this on Stack Overflow.)

```js
message.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
  let lastMessage = message.first();
    if (message.channel.lastMessage = 'channel-id'){
      console.log(lastMessage.red);
  }
})
```

(Note that when I say `'channel-id'` I mean the actual ID of the channel.)

The error I am getting is that `message.first` is not a thing.

**How do I fix this error, and how can I get the most recent message in discord.js?**

Edit: The exact error I got is this:

```
(node:12352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: messages.first is not a function
    at C:\Users\[user redacted]\Desktop\SchoBot\index.js:57:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:12352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Below is the edit for the **3rd comment** on this question (sorted by oldest):

```js
  message.channel.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
    let lastMessage = message.channel.first();
      if (message.channel.lastMessage = 'channel-id'){
        console.log(lastMessage.red);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `message.channel.messages.fetch()` instead of `message.channel.fetch()`.

I didn't find the `message.first` function in the discord.js documentation, so I am not sure if it works. But you don't really need that function to fetch a message. The fetch function already did that for you.

In your case, the option `limit: 1` will only return the most recent message, which is the command you use to trigger the fetch. If you want to fetch the most recent message but not your command, you should use `limit: 2` instead and remove your command in the object later.
The fetch function will return an object containing message id and the content.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `message.fetch` needs to be `message.channel.fetch`

Comment: It still gives me the error. I think it has something to do with ```message.first```. I also tried ```messages.first```, but it still did not work. But yes, I think what you typed solved half of my problem, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so 17 minutes later and 1 stack overflow post read:

I think message.first is deprecated. I am using ```channel.lastMessage``` and it seems to work.

Comment: What happens if you change `message.first()` to `message.channel.first()`?

Comment: ```(node:13124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.first is not a function```

That is for the code I put all the way at the bottom of this question (to enable formatting)

Comment: It's most likely deprecated then I guess, I assume It's working with `message.channel.fetch` & `message.channel.lastMessage`?

Comment: No... it's giving me an error "channel is not defined" message (I may be having a complete brain fart and the JavaScript used to code this is really easy)

Comment: Is it giving you that error for the second or third line of the last piece of code you put in your question?